# How to change Data Source in Power Query for Pivot Data? (Browse Button missing)

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016, power-query

Ok, short explanation what I did: I created a Report in a Workbook ("Main File") linked with Power Query to another Workbook ("Source") which contains my data source. I have multiple Queries, 8 of them are just links and one loads the data to the Pivot Table which is the base of my report.
The Source will be updated once a month (not prepared by me) and so I need to change the data source of my Main File. Quite easy so far, I use the way described in the two picture below and it worked for the last three months perfectly fine from my PC. ([Ribbon]Data -> [Dropdown]New Query -> Data Source Settings... -> Change Source... -> **Browse...** --> Update the Query)

[Step 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wN6LH.jpg)

[Step 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kaLFx.jpg)

But now the problem starts. I uploaded the file to the server folder and wanted to show my college how to do it. Everything worked fine but when it came to the point to select the new data source there was **no "Browse" Button** and when he changed the path to source data by hand it just gave back an error that the path doesn't exist.

Both workbooks lie on the same server, we both have full access rights to the server and we both run Office 365 ProPlus with the newest update (he just has another update channel than me).

I would be happy about any suggestion how to solve that problem!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it turned out that I now works manually and the problem in the was just the path itself. There is still no Browse Button, but he will survive that I guess.